# How to iterate URLs to the curl command?

Tags: python, bash, web-scraping, scripting, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm new to web scraping and I'm using both python and bash scripts to get the information I need. I'm running with WSL( windows subsystem for Linux) and for some reason, the scripts are running with git-bash. 
I'm trying to create a bash script that downloads the Html of a webpage, it then sends to a python script which returns 2 txt files with the links to other webpages. The original script then iterates through one of the txt file's links and downloads the html content of each webpage to file named after a specific part of the link. But this final loop doesn't work.
If I write the links to the curl command by hand, it works. But if I try to run the script it doesn't work.
This is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl http://mythicspoiler.com/sets.html |
cat >>mainpage.txt
python creatingAListOfAllExpansions.py #returns two txt files containing the expansion links and the commander decks' links
rm mainpage.txt

#get the pages from the links
cat commanderDeckLinks.txt |
while read a ; do
    curl $a |          ##THIS DOESN'T WORK
    cat >>$(echo $a | cut --delimiter="/" -f4).txt
done
```

I've tried several different ways and saw similar problems, but for the life of me, I can't figure this one out. It always appears the same error:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

This is the content of commanderDeckLinks.txt:

```
http://mythicspoiler.com/cmd/index.html
http://mythicspoiler.com/c13/index.html
http://mythicspoiler.com/c14/index.html
http://mythicspoiler.com/c15/index.html
http://mythicspoiler.com/c16/index.html
http://mythicspoiler.com/c17/index.html
http://mythicspoiler.com/c18/index.html
http://mythicspoiler.com/c19/index.html
http://mythicspoiler.com/c20/index.html
```

This is the python script

```
#reads the main page of the website
with open("mainpage.txt") as datafile:
    data = datafile.read()

#gets the content after the first appearance of the introduced string
def getContent(data, x):
    j=0
    content=[]
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if(data[i].strip().startswith(x) and j == 0):
            j=i
        if(i>j and j != 0):
            content.append(data[i])
    return content

#gets the content of the website that is inside the body tag
mainNav = getContent(data.splitlines(), "<!--MAIN NAVIGATION-->")

#gets the content of the website that is inside of the outside center tags
content = getContent(mainNav, "<!--CONTENT-->")

#removes extra content from list
def restrictNoise(data, string):
    content=[]
    for i in data:
        if(i.startswith(string)):
            break
        content.append(i)
    return content

#return only lines which are links
def onlyLinks(data):
    content=[]
    for i in data:
        if(i.startswith("<a")):
            content.append(i)
    return content


#creates a list of the ending of the links to later fetch
def links(data):
    link=[]
    for i in data:
        link.append(i.split('"')[1])
    return link

#adds the rest of the link
def completLinks(data):
    completeLinks=[]
    for i in data:
        completeLinks.append("http://mythicspoiler.com/"+i)
    return completeLinks

#getting the commander decks
commanderDecksAndNoise = getContent(content,"<!---->")
commanderDeck = restrictNoise(commanderDecksAndNoise, "<!---->")
commanderDeckLinks = onlyLinks(commanderDeck)
commanderDecksCleanedLinks = links(commanderDeckLinks)

#creates a txt file and writes in it
def writeInTxt(nameOfFile, restrictions, usedList):
    file = open(nameOfFile,restrictions)
    for i in usedList:
        file.write(i+"\n")
    file.close()

#creating the commander deck text file
writeInTxt("commanderDeckLinks.txt", "w+", completLinks(commanderDecksCleanedLinks))

#getting the expansions
expansionsWithNoise = getContent(commanderDecksAndNoise, "<!---->")
expansionsWithoutNoise = restrictNoise(expansionsWithNoise, "</table>")
expansionsLinksWNoise = onlyLinks(expansionsWithoutNoise)
expansionsCleanedLinks = links(expansionsLinksWNoise)

#creating the expansions text file
writeInTxt("expansionLinks.txt", "w+", completLinks(expansionsCleanedLinks))
```

If more information is needed to solve my problem, please tell me. And thank you to everyone who tried to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the line endings for bash(Linux) and windows are different, LF and CRLF, respectively (I'm not too sure, as this is all new to me). So when I created a file with items separated by lines in python, the bash script couldn't read it very well as the file created had CRLF endings and the bash script was reading only the LF, rendering the URLs useless because they had a CR ending that wasn't supposed to be there. I didn't know how to solve this using bash code, but what I did was create a file (with python) with each item separated by underscores, "_", and added the last item, n, just so that I would never have to deal with line endings. Then I just ran a for loop in bash iterating by each item separated by underscores, except the last item. This solved the problem.